# Проверка данных на входе

Tags: php, laravel

Ребята подскажите пожалуйста.
Есть задача, сделать веб. форму которая будет принемать Имя, Телефон, Промо-код.
Человек вводит свои данные, и если его введенный промо-код совпадет с промо-кодом который в таблице уже есть, то сохранить данные в таблицу.
Для этой задачи я сделал 2 таблицы, Clients, Codes. И связал их между собой отношениями один ко многим и belongsTo.
Я сделал проверку в контроллере на совпадение промо-кода, и смог сделать что бы сохранялось в таблицу Clients, имя и телефон. 
Но что то не могу сообразить как сохранить client_id в таблицу Codes?
Это мне нужно для того что, потому что один юсер может иметь несколько промо-кодов.
И что бы в дальнейшем была возможность распечатать во вьюхе пользователей и их промо-коды которые есть у них.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ в [этом разделе](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models) документации.

Если у вас `Client` который `hasMany` `Code`, то чтобы добавить `Code` нужно:

```
$code = new \App\Code(['value' => '12345']);

$client->codes()->save($code);
```

При этом `client_id` для `Code` поставиться сам.

Есть еще следующие методы: `saveMany`, `create`, `createMany`.

Если нужно для `Code` задать клиента и есть связь `belongsTo` `Client`:

```
$code->client()->associate($client);
$code->save();
```

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, а как сделать проверку если промо-код который в форме совпадает с промо-кодом в таблице, то принять данные. То что я сделал, это пробегаюсь циклом foreach по переменной $codes и в нутри делаю проверку if ($input['z_code'] == $code->code) то сохраняю данные в таблицу. Но сейчас он проверяет только превую запись и все дальше цикл останавливается. А у меня в таблице 3 кода.

Comment: Пробегаться циклом очень плохая идея. Чтобы проверить есть ли промокод из формы в бд: `if ($code = \App\Code::where('code', $input['z_code'])->first()) { значит код есть, также тут доступен код который гашло, он в переменной $code }`

Comment: Илья спасибо вам что помогаете мне.

Comment: Илья, пожалуйста можно я к вам буду обращаться по вопросам по ларавелу когда буду застревать? У меня нет рядом опытного человека у которого можно спросить и по советоваться по данному фреймворку. Хочется научиться. Если да то отправьте вашу почту на мой емейл advanced315@gmail.com

Comment: Илья, что то у меня не получается внести client_id в таблицу codes. У меня все промо-коды уже внесены заранее в таблицу. Проверка промо-кода при отправке формы работает. А как реализовать что бы после сохранения имени и телефона в таблицу clients, далее сохранить client_id в таблицу codes? Я попробовал советами которые написали вышу, но не получилось.

Comment: Ура, все получилось. Сделал так: $client = Client::where('id', $client->id)->first(); $code->client()->associate($client); $code->save();

Comment: Илья спасибо большое!

Comment: Забыл про `$code->save();`, извините. Думаю о помощи сможем договориться, особенно за оплату. Ко мне так уже люди с этого сайта обращались)